# How to turn colors for vim.tiny without internet access?

Tags: colors, vi

`readlink -f 'which vi'` output:

```
/usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

`vi --version` output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 17 2016 07:08:19)
Included patches: 1-488, 576
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Small version without GUI.
```

As I was sad to learn, this type of vi version doesn't have colors by default.

`syntax on` isn't recognized. and my machine has no internet access (no `apt-get`).

I'm seeking for a savior to rescue my one-color solitude, please, is there any way to have a syntax highlighted vi in my situation?

Answer (score 2):

From the version number of your `vim`, it looks like you're running Debian Jessie. Since 2019-07-06, it's been the `oldoldstable` version, and so it's going to be obsolete soon. Just a thing to be aware of...

You'll need the [`vim-runtime`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/vim-runtime) package. It has no hard dependencies, so you could just get to some other computer with internet access, download that single package, bring it to your non-networked system and install it with `sudo dpkg -i vim-runtime*.dpkg`.

I think that will get you at least some syntax highlighting and color support. The `termguicolors` feature that is missing from `vim-tiny` refers to full 24-bit color support on Xterms and compatible terminal emulators.